# Weird output from `corrplot`

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I am working with corrplot library and this is the code:

```
corrplot(correlation_matrix, method = "number", 
         number.cex = 0.6,
         tl.col = "black", 
         type = "lower", 
         tl.srt = 45)
```

Surprisingly it outputs this strange plot:
[image]

Any idea why this happens? I build the correlation matrix directly looking from the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I found out how to fix it. I have to specify "**corrplot::**" as follows:

```
corrplot::corrplot(correlation_matrix, method = "number", 
         number.cex = 0.6,
         tl.col = "black", 
         type = "lower", 
         tl.srt = 45)
```

And the result is:
[image]